# Demora no servidor para gravar e acessar informações

Tags: php, mysql, servidor

Bom dia/tarde/noite a todos, estou com um problema em dois sites php-mysql;

Antes de tudo quero que entendam a situação, possuo 2 sites que gravam informações na mesma base, o **site 1** é hospedado no mesmo servidor da base, e o **site 2** possui um servidor somente para ele.

O problema é que o **site 1**(que possui a mesma base no mesmo servidor) demora cerca de 2-3 segundos para acessar e gravar informações, já o **site** 2 (que efetua uma conexão no servidor do site 1) grava instantaneamente.

Os códigos não são um problema, pois até mesmo em uma simples consulta tem essa diferença de tempo e ambos utilizam o mysql-connect();

Versão do mysql = 5.5.47;

Obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

- Verifique se as queries executadas são as mesmas, se não tem "select" grande no Site 1, isso pode mudar a velocidade;
- O host do banco de dados do Site 1 está configurado como "localhost"? Se ele estiver configurado com uma URL e o servidor de DNS não for local, pode dar atraso também;
- Ao abrir o Site 1, você chama algum plugin JavaScript, CSS ou etc, que não está hospedado no mesmo servidor?